# Anychart chart in email body as image

Tags: javascript, html, anychart

I am trying to embed the chart into the email body on click of a Send button. I have gone through the [Server-side_Rendering](http://docs.anychart.com/7.11.0/Common_Settings/Server-side_Rendering) of anychart documentation, but not able to get a proper output. If anybody is used this before and can give me solution for this will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the 7.12.0 version: you can set the parameters of the image (dimensions, quality, extension and so on) as the optional request parameters of export server.

You'll find the full list of parameters below:
http://docs.anychart.com/7.12.0/Common_Settings/Server-side_Rendering#web_server_usage